# How to display line number of sentence (muliple line) in the first line?

Tags: python

In test.txt, I have 2 lines of sentences.

```
The heart was made to be broken.
There is no surprise more magical than the surprise of being loved.
```

In the codes:

```
import re
file = open('test.txt','r')#specify file to open
data = file.readlines()
file.close()

print "---------------------------------------------------"
count = 0
for line in data:
    line_split = re.findall(r'[^ \t\n\r, ]+',line)
    count = count + 1
    def chunks(line_split, n):
        for i in xrange(0, len(line_split), n):
            yield line_split[i:i+n]

    separate_word = list(chunks(line_split, 8))

    for i, word in enumerate(separate_word, 1):
        print count, ' '.join(word)
    print "---------------------------------------------------"
```

Results from the codes:

```
---------------------------------------------------
1 The heart was made to be broken.
---------------------------------------------------
2 There is no surprise more magical than the
2 surprise of being loved.
---------------------------------------------------
```

Is there any possible way for displaying the number of sentence in the first line only?

Expect results:

```
---------------------------------------------------
1 The heart was made to be broken.
---------------------------------------------------
2 There is no surprise more magical than the
  surprise of being loved.
---------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Don't add the language name to the title - that's what tags are for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply check if it's the first line:

```
for i, word in enumerate(separate_word):
    if i == 0:
        print count, ' '.join(word)
    else:
        print " ", ' '.join(word)
```

I strongly suggest you use [the `with` statement](http://docs.python.org/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement) to open the file. This is more readable and handles closing the file for you, even on exceptions.

Another good idea is to loop directly over the file - this is a better idea as it doesn't load the entire file into memory at once, which is not needed and could cause problems with big files.

You should also use [`enumerate()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#enumerate) as you have done here for the loop over `data`, as that way you will not to manually deal with `count`.

You are also defining `chunks()` repeatedly, which is a little pointless, better to define it once at the beginning. Where calling it, there is also no need to make a list - we can iterate directly over the generator.

If we correct all of this, we get the cleaner:

```
import re

def chunks(line_split, n):
    for i in xrange(0, len(line_split), n):
        yield line_split[i:i+n]

print "---------------------------------------------------"

with open("test.txt", "r") as file:
    for count, line in enumerate(file, 1):
        line_split = re.findall(r'[^ \t\n\r, ]+',line)
        separate_word = chunks(line_split, 8)
        for i, word in enumerate(separate_word):
            if i == 0:
                print count, ' '.join(word)
            else:
                print " ", ' '.join(word)

        print "---------------------------------------------------"
```

It's also worth noting the variable names are a little misleading `word`, for example, is not a word.

Comment: @ThanaDaray Note my change from `enumerate(separate_word, 1)` to `enumerate(separate_word)`.

Comment: -.- i knew. It said I have to wait 8 minutes.

Comment: @ThanaDaray Of course, just letting you know in case you didn't.

Comment: @ThanaDaray What isn't, sorry?

Answer (score 0):

Python comes with text wrapping built in. I admit that the formatting below isn't perfect, but you'll get the idea :-)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
import textwrap

with open('test.txt') as fd:
    T = [line.strip() for line in fd]

for n, s in enumerate(T):
    print '-'*42
    sys.stdout.write("%d " % n)
    for i in textwrap.wrap(s, 45):
        sys.stdout.write("%s\n" % i)
print '-'*42
```

Outputs:

```
------------------------------------------
0 The heart was made to be broken.
------------------------------------------
1 There is no surprise more magical than the
surprise of being loved.
------------------------------------------
```